[flutterfire]: PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file 'android/build.gradle' when running flutterfire configure
Q) Is there an existing issue for this?

I have searched the existing issues.

Q) Which plugins are affected?

Other

Q) Which platforms are affected?

Android, iOS, macOS, Web, Windows

Description

When running the flutterfire configure command to set up Firebase for a Flutter project, the process fails with a PathNotFoundException error. The error indicates that the build.gradle file in the [android] directory cannot be found. This issue occurs even though the Firebase configuration for Android, iOS, macOS, web, and Windows platforms is successfully registered.

Reproducing the issue
flutter create example
cd example
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
flutterfire configure

error
Firebase Core version
3.9.0
Flutter Version
3.28.0-2.0.pre.38577 • channel master
Tried to downgrade the flutter sdk version but it is a bad idea

How about creating the file?

I am noob. My coding sucks I can't just create  build.gradle file and remove the Kotlin DSL to Groovy DSL on my own.

I just changed the channel to stable and it works :)

you have to first login firebase from your terminal.
You can see the steps from here
If you are logged in,
firebase logout

And then login again
firebase login

From firebase console add the project and follow the adding flutter app instructions.
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
flutterfire configure --project='project-name'

After you see firebase_options.dart in your system, you have to add this code to your main.dart
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);


How would that help with a file that is missing?

I added a link for the steps before flutterfire configuration

OP is already performing dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli which means the login command was already issued. Still don't see how this would generate the config file that's missing?

dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli seems activated but after you logout and login again, it works for me.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

@LinDu I add the installation. thanks ;)
